# When files are selected repeatedly or files in Excel format, this exception is thrown

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, filestream, sqldatareader

Either FileStream or Process, how can I figure it out?

The following windows forms application first selects one or more files from openFileDialog1, checks to see if these files were in the database (GetInsertNummer), and writes them to the database (InsertInTable).

Then it reads them from database and writes in Windows (FileGetSimple). Next, these files are opened, closed, and then sent by Email (CreateMessage).

Everything seems to work fine, but when files are selected repeatedly or files in Excel format, this exception is thrown.

> The process cannot access the file '' because it is being used by another process.

When running the program, I press only once the button (btnSales_Click.) For the first time, everything goes fine.

```
   public bool FileGetSimple(int Identifier, string filePath)
        {
            pa = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), Path.GetFileName(filePath));

            var statement = "SELECT Id, Data, FileName FROM StoredFile WHERE Id = @id;";
            var mc = MakeConnection(statement);


            mc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", Identifier);
            SqlDataReader reader = mc.ExecuteReader();

            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                reader.Read();

                // the blob field
                int ndx = reader.GetOrdinal("Data");

                var blob = new Byte[(reader.GetBytes(ndx, 0, null, 0, int.MaxValue))];

                reader.GetBytes(ndx, 0, blob, 0, blob.Length);
                reader.Close();


                using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(pa, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite))
                {
                    fs.Write(blob, 0, blob.Length);


                }

                OpenFiles(pa);

            }

            return true;

        }
```

Comment: TLDR : Please shorten your code limiting it to the part that contains the actual problem.

Comment: Firrst, you have `files = new List<string>();` inside a loop, so you actually only get the last file selected. Then, if you `Process.Start()` and Excel file, the file will be locked until closed, so `File.ReadAllBytes()` cannot get you anything but an exception. Do as suggested in the previous comment.

Comment: Hallo, either  here     `using (var fs = new FileStream(pa, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None))
                    {
                        fs.Write(blob, 0, blob.Length);

                    }` oder here                    `message.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(item));`

Comment: This code doesn't even compile. You use `InformationWindow` but only supply one string parameter where it requires two. Also `MailAddress("---",--- );` there's a `---` that's not a string or whatever? What is that supposed to be?

Comment: Hallo , use valid e-mail address and it should work.You are right InformationWindow  requires two parameter like this   `public DialogResult InformationWindow(string v1, string v2, MessageBoxButtons oKCancel, MessageBoxIcon information)`

Answer (score 1):

Reviewed your code (in comments):

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public List<string> files { get; set; }
        public List<string> outputfiles { get; set; }

        // these fields are public but not properties, why?
        public int insertNummer;
        public int row_id;
        public Process sp;
        public string ExceptionMessage { get; set; }

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnSales_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            outputfiles = null;
            files = null;
            sp = null;

            // didn't compile
            if (InformationWindow("Выбирете пожалйста фалы и сохраните в Windows", "", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Information) == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                // invert and return
                if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    foreach (var item in openFileDialog1.FileNames)
                    {
                        files = new List<string>();
                        files.Add(item);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    // useless since files is already null at this point
                    files = null;
                }

                GetInsertNummer(@"SELECT (SELECT MAX(id) FROM StoredFile) id, MAX(InsertNummer) InsertNummer FROM StoredFile");

                // useless if return above
                if (files != null)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < files.Count; i++)
                    {
                        InsertInTable(i);

                        // use ++row_id in FileGetSimple instead
                        row_id++;

                        FileGetSimple(row_id, files[i]);
                    }
                    // doesn't compile
                    InformationWindow("Все в порядке с выбранными файлами?", "", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
                    CreateMessage("smtp.strato.de");

                    MessageBox.Show("success");
                }
            }
        }

        public DialogResult InformationWindow(string v1, string v2, MessageBoxButtons oKCancel, MessageBoxIcon information)
        {
            // bad practise, rename v1 to caption and v2 to message in method parameter
            string message = v2;
            string caption = v1;
            // unnecessary variable definitions, also weird name "oKCancel" for dynamically assigned MessageBoxButtons that aren't always Ok/Cancel?
            MessageBoxButtons buttons = oKCancel;
            DialogResult result;

            // Displays the MessageBox.
            // return the value directly instead of an unneeded assignment
            return result = MessageBox.Show(message, caption, buttons, information);
        }

        public void CreateMessage(string server)
        {
            using (SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(server))
            {
                client.Port = 587;
                client.EnableSsl = true;

                client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("s.dadashev@gebr-naim.de", "");

                // didn't compile ---
                MailAddress from = new MailAddress("---", "");
                MailAddress to = new MailAddress("---", "");
                MailMessage message = new MailMessage(from, to);

                message.Subject = "Es funktioniert.";
                // unnecessary @
                message.Body = @"Вы получили письмо с вложением";

                // outputfiles will always only contain a single file --> the loop will only run once, ever!
                foreach (var item in outputfiles)
                {
                    // dispose of possibly previously disposed process, not necessary or using statement of sp not necessary
                    if (!sp.HasExited)
                    {
                        sp.Kill();
                    }
                    else
                        sp = null;

                    message.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(item));
                }

                InformationWindow("Success", $"Sending an email message to" + to.Address + " by using the SMTP host " + client.Host + ".", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

                try
                {
                    client.Send(message);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    InformationWindow("Exception", ex.ToString(), MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                }
            }
        }

        private void InsertInTable(int i)
        {
            // **** Write BLOB to the Database
            byte[] filebyte = File.ReadAllBytes(files[i]);

            // unnecessary variable declaration (it's only used once), put statement directly in MakeConnection("...")
            string sql = @"insert into StoredFile(FileName,Data,InsertNummer,Date) values(@FileName,@Data,@InsertNummer,@Date)";

            var cmd = MakeConnection(sql);

            // unnecessary variable declarations, parameter1..5 is never used anywhere
            SqlParameter parameter1 = cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FileName", Path.GetFileName(files[i]));
            SqlParameter parameter2 = cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Data", filebyte);
            SqlParameter parameter3 = cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@InsertNummer", insertNummer);
            SqlParameter parameter4 = cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", row_id);
            SqlParameter parameter5 = cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", DateTime.Now);

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

        public bool FileGetSimple(int Identifier, string filePath)
        {
            // why did you start using var instead of the types?
            var pa = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), Path.GetFileName(filePath));

            var statement = "SELECT Id, Data, FileName FROM StoredFile WHERE Id = @id;";
            var mc = MakeConnection(statement);

            mc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", Identifier);
            SqlDataReader reader = mc.ExecuteReader();

            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                reader.Read();

                // the blob field
                int ndx = reader.GetOrdinal("Data");

                // that is wrong and not how to read a buffer, read up on how to use buffers/GetBytes correctly!
                var blob = new Byte[(reader.GetBytes(ndx, 0, null, 0, int.MaxValue))];
                // oh jeez
                reader.GetBytes(ndx, 0, blob, 0, blob.Length);
                reader.Close();

                try
                {
                    if (File.Exists(pa))
                    {
                        File.Delete(pa);
                    }

                    using (var fs = new FileStream(pa, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None))
                    {
                        fs.Write(blob, 0, blob.Length);
                    }
                }
                catch (IOException e)
                {
                    InformationWindow("Warning", e.Message + " Schlie&#223;en Sie diese Datei, um fortzusetzen.", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
                    FileGetSimple(Identifier, filePath);
                }
            }

            // function is called OpenFiles but only a single file is supplied?
            OpenFiles(pa);

            return true;
        }

        private void OpenFiles(string tempFilePath)
        {
            // what is this even supposed to do?
            // create new process instance
            using (sp = new Process())
            {
                // then throw away the instance and start a process instead
                sp = Process.Start(tempFilePath);
                // then dispose process
            }
            // quiz: has new Process() or Process.Start been disposed by the using statement?

            // every time a file is opened the outputfiles list is re-initialized and a single element is addded?
            // it's never going to contain more than one element!
            outputfiles = new List<string>();
            outputfiles.Add(tempFilePath);
        }

        public void GetInsertNummer(string ins_num_query)
        {
            // using dynamic sql statements but accessing columns statically, how do you guarantee that these columns exist?
            // is there a point in providing a parameter, why can the statement not be inside this function, it never changes!
            var ins_num = MakeConnection(ins_num_query);
            SqlDataReader read_ins_nummer = ins_num.ExecuteReader();

            while (read_ins_nummer.Read())
            {
                int ins = read_ins_nummer.GetOrdinal("InsertNummer");
                int ins_id = read_ins_nummer.GetOrdinal("Id");
                // use previously defined variable "ins" instead of re-executing GetOrdial
                if (!read_ins_nummer.IsDBNull(read_ins_nummer.GetOrdinal("InsertNummer")))
                {
                    // insertNummer and row_id is the same, dont' execute GetInt32 twice, use the same value instead!
                    insertNummer = read_ins_nummer.GetInt32(ins);
                    row_id = read_ins_nummer.GetInt32(ins_id);
                    insertNummer++;
                }
                else
                {
                    insertNummer = 1;
                    row_id = 0;
                }
            }
        }

        public SqlCommand MakeConnection(string sql)
        {
            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("");
            connection.Open();

            // you're using object initializer here, why not everywhere else?
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand() { Connection = connection, CommandText = sql })
            {
                try
                {
                    return cmd;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    // this is never used anywhere
                    ExceptionMessage = ex.Message;
                    return cmd;
                }
            }
        }

        private void exitToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }
    }
```

Hard to read and even harder to figure out what is supposed to be happening. It looks like copy/paste code from different tutorials and Stack Overflow posts. Do *you* know what is happening? How should *I*?

Also,

> Either FileStream or Process, how can I figure it out?

How do you not know? You're getting the exception, you should know where the exception occurs.

Sorry this answer isn't useful but it's probably the best you're going to get. Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and ask again.